# How to return custom dictionary as response for a "create" method in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Im Using django rest framework for my current project.Im using a nested serializer.

```
class FirstSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
      field_one = serializers.CharField()
      field_two = serializers.CharField()

class SecondSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
      my_field = FirstSerializer(many=True)

      def create(self, validated_data):
          custom_dictionary = {}
          return custom_dictionary
```

This is where am stucked up.I've been doing some operations in SecondSerializer now I need to return a custom dictionary without the key "my_field" on response.

Comment: simple way is remove key from the serializer data, can you please show your apiview? and may be `Class` should be the `class`?

Comment: remove key from serializer data ? how ? this is my view:
class Myview(ListCreateApiView):
      serialzier_classes = SecondSerializer

Comment: @BearBrown I don't think it's a good choice since it may affect the **write process/serialization process**. `write_only=True` will be good, right?